# How to create a my account page in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to create a my account page where users can view their information that they have input into the site on a register page. i only want it to display the information of the user that is currently logged in.

this is my what i have so far but it doesnt work

```
<?php
   include_once('DBconnect.php');


    $sql= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
      $username = $row['username'];
      $firstname = $row['first_name'];
      $lastname = $row['last_name'];
      $email = $row['email'];
      $school = $row['school'];
      $topics .= "<tr><td>username:".$username." </td><td>First name:".$firstname."</td><td>Last name:".$lastname."</td><td>email: ".$email."</td><td>school: ".$school."</td></tr>";
  echo $topics;
  } ?>
```

Comment: try to use mysqli_* rather than use mysql. where do you pass your $username?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is pretty vague - is it giving a specific error?

Comment: I don't see where `$username` was defined in your code, are you saving into a session? did it come from a previous login page? Provide more information pls

Comment: its giving no errors, its just not showing any results when i build it. im not entirely sure how to do this.

Comment: Are you able to connect to your database?

Comment: where your $username come from? do you define it ?

Comment: $username i assumed was the session user who had logged in

Answer (score 0):

try encapsulating your mysql_fetch_assoc() in a function that returns an array result set like so:

```
 function populate_array($res) {
  while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($res) {
     $result_array[] = $row;
  }
  return $result_array;
}
```

then use a for loop to iterate through result set like so:

```
$result = populate_array($res);
$sets = count($result);

for($i=0;$i<$sets;$i++) {
  $topics .= $result[$i]['username'] . $result[$i]['firstname'] . $result[$i]['lastname']; // continue
}

echo $topics;
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does your variable `$username` come from? Your code seems fine. Do you get any errors? Some improvements you can make are:

1. Use Mysqli_* extenstion or PDO extension because mysql_* is outdated and will be removed soon
2. Escape your variables before you put them in a query by using:

   - mysql_real_escape_string()
   - mysqli_real_escape_string()
   - PDO::quote()
   - Or prepared statements with mysqli and PDO

You can try to add:

```
if (!$res) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found";
    exit;
}
```

And see if you get an error

edit:

Your username usually comes from your form or if the user is already logged in from the `$_SESSION[]` Global. But if the user is logged in you can better store all the info to the session so you don't have to request that information from the DB all the time.

If the user is logged in successfully you have to call `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;`
then in this page you can call `$username = $_SESSION['username'];`

And don't forget to call `session_start();` on each page that uses sessions

Comment: this is what i got when i put in your code.

Notice: Undefined variable: uid in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\Site\My account.php on line 30
No rows found

Comment: The reason you get 'No rows found' is because you haven't specified your username so it doesn't return anything. I don't know where the uid is coming from. I don't see it anywhere on this page. Could you post your DBconnect.php. I adapted my answer with some extra explanation

Answer (score 0):

you need to call you $username from the session, try below code :

```
<?php
   include_once('DBconnect.php');

    $username = $_SSESSION['username'];
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
      $username = $row['username'];
      $firstname = $row['first_name'];
      $lastname = $row['last_name'];
      $email = $row['email'];
      $school = $row['school'];
      $topics .= "<tr><td>username:".$username." </td><td>First name:".$firstname."</td><td>Last name:".$lastname."</td><td>email: ".$email."</td><td>school: ".$school."</td></tr>";
  echo $topics;
  } ?>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\Site\My account.php on line 30 i get this error when i try this code

Comment: you copy paste my code? which username occur error? you change $username to $name and see what result return

Comment: Yeah i copied your code and in the first one underneath include_once. i've tried changing it to $name and i get the same error. i can get an output of all the results with this code but i only need it for the current user who is logged in

Comment: You confirm that is the session[username] is same like what you define previously?